# Node JS: Loop round grouped by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, foreach, reduce

I've got data like this

```
[
  [ '@test','1.2.6-unstable' ],
  [ '@test','1.3.2-unstable' ],
  [ '@test','1.4.6-unstable' ],
  [ '@test2','4.0.1-unstable' ],
  [ '@test2','4.0.2-unstable' ],
  [ '@test2','4.0.3-unstable' ],
  [ '@test3','2.2.0-unstable' ],
  [ '@test3','2.2.3-unstable' ],
  [ '@test3','2.2.9-unstable' ],
...
]
```

and I'm trying to group them by name `@test` then loop round the values and apply an action on each value in the new arrays, ignoring the first value.
My output should be

```
[
  [ '@test','1.3.2-unstable' ],
  [ '@test','1.4.6-unstable' ]
]
```

```
[
  [ '@test2','4.0.2-unstable' ],
  [ '@test2','4.0.3-unstable' ]
]
```

```
[
  [ '@test3','2.2.3-unstable' ],
  [ '@test3','2.2.9-unstable' ]
]
```

I have looked at these questions and I'm unable to apply the right combination to get what I need
[break array of objects into separate arrays based on a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696326/break-array-of-objects-into-separate-arrays-based-on-a-property)
[Can't loop over grouped array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661181/cant-loop-over-grouped-array-in-js)
[JS loop through array and group with map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055027/js-loop-through-array-and-group-with-map)
I've also tried `.shift()` and `.slice(1)` but this only takes the 1st one off the whole original array

My code looks like this:

```
const response = await axios.get(reportURL, { headers });
const mystuff = response.data.value.reduce((acc, next) => {
  acc.push(...next.versions.map((v) => [next.name, v.version]));
  return acc;
}, []);
const filteredArray = mystuff.filter(([_, version]) => version.includes('-unstable'));
const map = filteredArray.reduce((acc, { name, version }) => {
  if (acc.has(name)) {
    acc.get(name).versions.push(version);
  } else {
    acc.set(name, { name, versions: [version] });
  }
  return acc;
}, new Map());

const result = [...map.values()];

// Loop round the array and fire off the axios
result.forEach(([name, version]) => {
  const URL = `https:URL/${name}/versions/${version}?api-version=7.1-preview.1`;
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77641179/node-js-get-all-values-of-key-in-array-of-objects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77652493/node-js-evaluate-value-inside-array-of-objects...  Why don't you just show us the big picture? What is the input and what ultimately needs to be done?

Comment: Sorry @gog I thought it was clear with what I put in the question. The big picture is I'm interrogating Azure Feeds to find all packages with `-unstable` appended, ignore the first 3 found versions then delete the rest. Using axios get and delete for this as there is no corresponding `az` command.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by the first item of the nested arrays with [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) and take only the values.

Finally remove the first item of each group result.

```js
const
    data = [['@test','1.2.6-unstable'], [ '@test','1.3.2-unstable'], ['@test','1.4.6-unstable'], ['@test2','4.0.1-unstable'], ['@test2','4.0.2-unstable'], ['@test2','4.0.3-unstable'], ['@test3','2.2.0-unstable'], ['@test3','2.2.3-unstable'], ['@test3','2.2.9-unstable']],
    grouped = Object
        .values(Object.groupBy(data, ([first]) => first))
        .map(a => a.slice(1));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without `groupBy`

```js
const
    data = [['@test','1.2.6-unstable'], [ '@test','1.3.2-unstable'], ['@test','1.4.6-unstable'], ['@test2','4.0.1-unstable'], ['@test2','4.0.2-unstable'], ['@test2','4.0.3-unstable'], ['@test3','2.2.0-unstable'], ['@test3','2.2.3-unstable'], ['@test3','2.2.9-unstable']],
    grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((r, a) => {
        if (r[a[0]]) r[a[0]].push(a);
        else r[a[0]] = [];
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your code didn't remove first element of each list.

Comment: @J.Porter, right. please see edit.

Comment: Thank you @NinaScholz but this fails
`TypeError: Object.groupBy is not a function`

Comment: @martyzee, this a new implementation, meybe you need a newer js version.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I'm locked down to versions due to being on a corporate estate but thanks anyway :-)